# I want to Process Large Json File by URL to DB in Less Memory ysage PHP

Tags: php, json, memory-management

Hello I want to Parse a Large JSON File to MySQLi DB with Less Memory Usage 16M 
Is it Possible to Load a JSON file by URL and save it into DB by Background Processing ???

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15373529/parse-large-json-file and
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4049428/processing-large-json-files-in-php

Comment: @JessieJackson I checked all these not working in my case :(