# Trim big Json file with PHP

Tags: php, json

Hello guys I have a assignment, which I have honestly no idea how to complete. I have a huuuge Json file which is 22 GB big, so I have to get the data from it but it's full with empty spaces and new lines and I have to trimm does before even opening the file. I tried getting the data and trim it but it says it is out of memory I even set the memory limit to -1 if anyone has any idea how is that supposed to happen please I am open to suggestions.

Comment: have you tired chunking your trimming/reading process?

Comment: Look for a *JSON stream parser*, allowing you to read the file bit by bit and not in one chunk.

Comment: Post your code, errors, what you have tried.  We will not write the code for you.  That being said, @deceze beat me to it, you have to parse the file, not try to load it and process after.

Comment: So I guess the way is to read the JSON file line by line any idea how can I get each line without reading the whole file ?

Answer (score 3):

There is simple and cool parser for parsing large JSON files.

https://github.com/salsify/jsonstreamingparser

Also maybe you will find an answer on the following links 
[Parse large JSON file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15373529/parse-large-json-file) 
[Processing large JSON files in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4049428/processing-large-json-files-in-php)