# How to parse big JSON files with PHP

Tags: php, json

I need to parse a big JSON file (about 200MB). With json_decode I get a memory error

I have found [salsify/jsonstreamingparser](https://github.com/salsify/jsonstreamingparser) library that promise parser JSON documents. But I only have found in-memory examples that produce the same error of json_decode.

Anyone knows how can I parse large JSON files?

Comment: Raise your memory limit before parsing and lower it right after parsing. There really isn't much else you can do unless you contrive a hack with parsing the file using a C library and then reading it into PHP.

Comment: check this link you might get some help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15373529/parse-large-json-file

Comment: Increase memory limit is not an option.

Comment: @prakashtank I don't have clear how this lib is working https://github.com/kuma-giyomu/JSONParser

Comment: The streaming parser will only help if you want to extract or work on *parts* of the JSON data. It sounds like you want to decode the whole thing. If you don't have enough memory to even hold a single copy of the data there's no library on earth that can help you.

Comment: I want to decode the entire file, but in small piece of data. Parts by parts

Comment: Then look at something like the [SubsetConsumerListener](https://github.com/salsify/jsonstreamingparser/blob/master/src/Listener/SubsetConsumerListener.php) in the salsify package as a starting point for building what you want.

Comment: Not sure how to implement abstract protected function consume($data); method to get the data

Comment: does it provide pagination or limit?

Comment: No, At least I didn't find it. You need to consume data inside Listener. It should be great have pagination.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to iterate over it and do not demand to have the whole structure in memory at once, try https://github.com/halaxa/json-machine. It allows you to simply iterate over a JSON of any size/length **just using `foreach`.**

Comment: i wish this could work for all large json files :(

Comment: @ina, it should. Please tell me your problem in discussions on Github or file an issue. Thanks.

Comment: i read in issues that it doesn't work for huge json files with large elements but i'll try posting there oto

Answer (score -5):

Depending on what webserver or php-version you use. It is basicly possible to set a value for max-used-memory and max-used-script-execution-time.

See :

[PHP.NET - Limiting Ressources](http://php.net/manual/de/ini.core.php#ini.sect.resource-limits)

[PHP.NET - Limiting Execution-Time](http://php.net/manual/de/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time)

IMO PHP is not made for this kind of cpu-heavy operations, i would prefer to use it in the more common way - just use a mysql, postgres, ... So parse all your data in your favourite way in your database. Problem solved :)

... hope so. HF

Comment: I discarted this option, because the size of the file could be larger than my webserver memory allowed.