# Recommended or minimum server specifications for big json

Tags: mysql, json, server

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask this, but what do you guys recommend for storing json data or at least host a viewable json file?

A JSON link like this http://api.androidhive.info/volley/person_object.json
but with a size of 500mb worth of data (approx 16000 entries).

It needs cater at least a maximum of 15 concurrent users a day.

I bought a cheap vps around 2gb of ram, with 1 vCore 2.4 GHz and single request from the api caused the cpu spike to 100%. The json request mentioned is from a mysql query.

Comment: I guess you are parsing/decoding that json. You must use json parser which doesn't need the whole file in memory - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4049428/processing-large-json-files-in-php

Comment: @Marki555 do you mean parsing in server side rather than client side? i use json streaming to parse that very big json in client side.

Comment: You stream 500 MB json to client? ok :) Then store the json as files (in mysql store only the reference to filename), then you can stream the file from apache/php without having it whole in memory.