# how to Converting large JSON to array without using JSON_DECODE function

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a large sized JSON string of about 1 GB for example a JSON like

```
$someJSON = '[{"name":"Jonathan Suh","gender":"male"},{"name":"William 
Philbin","gender":"male"},{"name":"Allison McKinnery","gender":"female"}]';
```

I don't want to use `json_decode` to convert it to a PHP array as the JSON array is about 1 GB in size and it decoding fails with 500 error  Is it possible to break the JSON into smaller portions

```
$string1 = {"name":"Jonathan Suh","gender":"male"}
$string2 = {"name":"William Philbin","gender":"male"}
$string3 = {"name":"Allison McKinnery","gender":"female"}
```

and then convert it to an Array using `json_decode` for each variable of $string1, $string2 etc?

I cannot Split the array also as it will take more time.  Maybe something like scanning the JSON, storing to an array and then discarding the array using `unset()` line by line so that the memory will be freed after processing the array

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Processing large JSON files in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4049428/processing-large-json-files-in-php)

Comment: what will you end up doing with the data?

Comment: hi, I jusst need to calculate or total some fields and discard the array.